# Which preposition to use? (Again again)

Tags: prepositions

Darn prepositions making me all confused again, the sentence:

> the painting inspires the 60-year-old man, and he is passionately absorbed in his contemplation about his past

'about' sounds wrong, but I am not quite sure what should replace it, any suggestions?

I have tried doing some research, but I can't find similar examples through search engines, and my dictionaries are not helping.

Comment: *...contemplation **of** his past*. But I'd get rid of the preceding ***his***, since the repetition is awkward and semantically superfluous.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you, any suggestions to rewording?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Would "absorbed in his contemplation of the past" be correct?

Comment: That would be syntactically valid - but it's idiomatically less likely, and might not *mean* exactly the same. Obviously if the subject is "absorbed in contemplation", that can only be ***his*** contemplation, so as I said, it's superfluous to include the first possessive pronoun. But if you don't include the *second* one, we don't know ***whose*** past he's absorbed in contemplating. He might be thinking about how life was for dinosaurs, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sentence:

> the painting inspires the 60-year-old man, and he is passionately absorbed in his contemplation about his past.

My suggested rewrite:

> The painting inspires the 60-year-old man and causes him to be passionately absorbed in contemplation of his past.

Or,

> The painting inspires the 60-year-old man and causes him to be passionately absorbed in contemplating his past.

(I'm assuming that in addition to inspiring the man, the painting also triggers contemplating his past.)

Another possibility, with fewer words:

> The painting inspires the 60-year-old man and causes him to contemplate his past.

Or,

> In addition to inspiring the 60-year-old man, the painting also caused him to contemplate his past.

As you can tell, I'm not that passionate bout the word *passionately*, but you can insert it if you must. A better word might be *intently*.